# Remove all unused resources from an android project

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to remove all unused layouts, strings, drawables, colors, etc from my Android res directory. Are there any tools that will give me a list of files and I can remove from my repository and elements within specifics files (e.g. unused string entries) that are no longer used?

Answer (score 930, accepted):

You can easily search for unused resources from Android Studio. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and type "**unused resources**" (without quotes). That will execute lint. Super easy way to run lint commands (and other stuff from IDE).

OR

In **Android Studio Menu** > **Refactor** > **Remove Unused Resources...**

Select the resources you want to remove. You can exclude resources you want to keep by right-clicking on the resource item.

Use **Do Refactor** to remove all Resources at once.

**Update:** use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> for mac

Comment: cmd + Alt + Shift for mac

Comment: How do you delete all of them quickly?

Comment: @MikeMilla Right-click on the files you wish to delete and click on the option that says "Apply Lint Fixes". To delete multiple files in one go, select them.

Comment: Be advised that using this approach will also remove any resource that was used programmatically.

Comment: Broke my whole project... Not such a wise move

Comment: It does not seem to recognize used resources from other labels than "android", so if you use them I don't recommend this utility

Comment: As with all IntelliJ products, you can also use ctrl-shift-a and then start typing "remove unused resources" (no quotes) and then hit enter.

Comment: Be warned: Android lint in latest AS 3.0 will report a string resource as unused if it is only used in a layout file in data bidning code suc h as this:
"<TextView android:text="@{localizationManager.getString(R.string.OK)}"

Be very careful with this suggetsion!

Comment: With AS 3.0, this feature remove some used layout file. Better make a backup or git commit before trying this.

Comment: BE WARNED: It will remove views that use binding.

Comment: can anyone explain , how does removal of extra resources help ?

Comment: The APK size, your users download, is smaller when you don't bundle unused resources in. Also, it makes your project easier to orient in when there isn't unnecessary clutter. And the last that comes to my mind is when you have shrinkResources turned on, then you don't process unreferenced files all over and over again.

Comment: Please use that with extreme CAUTION since it might create untraceable bugs. Check my answer below.

Comment: WARNING : It will delete all files, drawables and assets which you are using programmatically. so make sure before doing this.

Comment: Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: Control + Z? Or recover a previous version of your files from Git.

Comment: Why in my project result is : `No suspicious code found. 1 214 files processed in 'Project` , but there are a lot of unused files?

Comment: It will delete assets that used in Data Binding too. Not reccomended. You can broke your project

Comment: Is there any way to remove Gradle distribution?

Comment: Alert - Before using these process, take a backup of your project. :)

Comment: This approach removes detects all ids which are access using ViewBinding as unused resources!!

Comment: @Calin do you have any suggestions to remove unused resources programmatically as well keeping the binding resources? Thanks

Comment: @Hadi do you have any suggestions to remove unused resources programmatically as well keeping the binding resources? Thanks

Comment: This is a great way to _find_ possibly unused resources. Do the _removal_ carefully & manually if you are concerned about breaking your code.

Answer (score 100):

Since ADT 16 you can use [Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint). It is really amazing tool.

> Android Lint is a new tool for ADT 16 (and Tools 16) which scans Android project sources for potential bugs.
>
> Here are some examples of the types of errors that it looks for:
>
> - Missing translations (and unused translations)
> - Layout performance problems (all the issues the old layoutopt tool used to find, and more)
> - Unused resources
> - Inconsistent array sizes (when arrays are defined in multiple configurations)
> - Accessibility and internationalization problems (hardcoded strings, missing contentDescription, etc)
> - Icon problems (like missing densities, duplicate icons, wrong sizes, etc)
> - Usability problems (like not specifying an input type on a text field)
> - Manifest errors and many more.

However, it has some issues (don't know if they're already fixed) and if you want to delete hundreds of supposedly unused resources I'd recommend to manually compile project several times during resource removing to be sure that Lint didn't remove something needed.

Comment: I wouldn't rely to heavily on what Lint is proposing as being unused resources especially if you do a lot of resource lookups in your code instead of in xml. Lint will in that case find a lot of resources not being used while they actually are.

Comment: In Android Studio, you can use `Analyze > Inspect Code...` to find a number of things, including **Unused Declarations and Methods**.

Comment: An example, if you want to use the command line: `lint --check UnusedResources <project-path>`

Comment: But how to delete them?

Comment: Is there a way to delete all the `Extra Translations` together/automatically?

Comment: @MartinPfeffer delete them with https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover

Comment: Only thing is that AS doesn't look for uses in code. It did found that there is no use of GLSL shaders code files for OpenGl, which in fact is loaded from resources.

Answer (score 48):

Since Support for the ADT in Eclipse has ended, we have to use Android Studio.

In Android Studio 2.0+ use `Refactor > Remove Unused Resources...`

[image]

Comment: Seems like that this way removes the resources used programmatically

Comment: Do not forget to Review in the next step, otherwise, some used files are also deleted.

Comment: Please take a backup of the whole project or just push to version control system before doing refactoring. I lost many drawables used, I was lucky to revert from the backup

Answer (score 46):

The Gradle build system for Android supports "resource shrinking": the automatic removal of resources that are unused, at build time, in the packaged app. In addition to removing resources in your project that are not actually needed at runtime, this also removes resources from libraries you are depending on if they are not actually needed by your application.

To enable this add the line shrinkResources true in your gradle file.

```
   android {
        ...

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true //Important step
                shrinkResources true
            }
   }
}
```

Check the official documentation here,

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking

Comment: shrinkResources need proguard to be enabled. i hv problems enabling proguard :-(

Comment: shrinkResources is taken into account only if minifyEnabled is true


 `minifyEnabled true`

Answer (score 19):

Beware if you are using multiple flavours when running lint. Lint may give false unused resources depending on the flavour you have selected.

Comment: How to avoid this?

Comment: Until now, I haven't found out a way of doing it. Except running lint for each flavour and then marking the items unused on both flavours.

Answer (score 17):

We open source a tool that removes all the unused resources in your android project based on the lint output.
It can be found here: https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover

Comment: how i use this to remove unused resource from my  android studio project.

Answer (score 13):

1--> In

> Android Studio Menu > Refactor > Remove Unused Resources

As Shown in Image Below:

[image]

**

> OR

**

2--> Second Way

-> **Ctrl Alt Shift i** and type "unused resources" (without quotes) in Windows

->  use **⌘ Option Shift i** for mac

or

-> cmd + Alt + Shift for mac

Comment: I added a random named string resource to the existing strings.xml file, and it didn't identify it as unused, so this doesn't work for that.

Comment: No it doesn't work for that, it works for drawable resources etc

Answer (score 12):

In Android Studio,

Analyze -> Run Inspection by Name

(Shortcut For Mac shift+command+option+i   , Ctrl + Shift + A on Windows/Linux).

And type 'unused resources'.

This way you can remove unused resources, variables ,symbols ,localization ,libraries ..etc.

Select the desired inspection from the list, then select inspection scope ->OK
[image]

Answer (score 9):

In Android Studio 2.0 and above
in menu select Refactor-->click on Remove Unused Resources...

(or)

shortcut also available

Press  **Ctlr+Alt+Shift+i**
one dialog box will apper, then type **unused** ,
you will find number of options 
select and remove unused resources

Answer (score 8):

**Attention Android Wear developers**: "Remove Unused Resources" will delete the xml file where you declare the capability name (res/values/wear.xml) and the phone won't be able to connect to the watch. I spent hours trying to figure out this bug in my app.

Comment: And also it removes round mipmap icons, for example.

Comment: Correct. In general, 'Remove Unused Resources' should not be recommended at all since it might create lots of untraceable bugs.

Answer (score 4):

To check string.xml.

It's easy (at least in my version of Eclipse)

In Eclipse for Android (I have version v22.6.2-1085508)

- Left click on the project name in "Package explorer"
- Select "Android Tools".
- Select "Run Lint: Check for common Errors".

Now when you open strings.xml, you will see that unused string are highlighted.

You can fix other potential issues.

Comment: +1 nice solution, buddy. It allows to run lint for selected checks as well - exactly what I needed .... (p.s. almost the same with Android Studio: right click in Project Explorer, select _Analyse_, select  _Inspect Code_ or _Run Inspection by Name_) :D

Comment: This does not help much in removing those unused strings. Do you suggest to remove them manually as before?

Comment: "Lint" is really an excellent way to "cleanup your project".  You still have to remove them manually, but they are highlighted and you immediately see that they are not used. It's a few minutes work for a medium size project. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe useful
Andround Unused Resources is a Java application that will scan your project for unused resources. Unused resources needlessly take up space, increase the build time, and clutter the IDE's autocomplete list.

To use it, ensure your working directory is the root of your Android project, and run:

java -jar AndroidUnusedResources.jar

https://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/

Comment: where ever I put it it keeps saying that is not the correct project root

Answer (score 3):

When we define shrink resources true that time we can also define which resources we wanna keep and which don't 
I have added xml file in res/raw folder named keep.xml

before going further generate a single signed build and check in apk analyser tool which will show drawable-xhdpi-v4 has messenger_button_send_round_shadow.png which i want to remove for this test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       tools:shrinkMode="strict"
       tools:discard="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue.png,
       @drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_white.png,
       @drawable/com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png,
       @drawable/messenger_button_send_round_shadow.png,
       @drawable/messenger_*"  />
```

by doing messenger_* all files starting from name messenger in drawable folder will be removed or other way around is i have defines specific file to be removed

so that way you can remove files from library it self
you can also remove layouts by @layout/layout name
if that drawable has been used by layout and so....

Answer (score 1):

There really excellent answers in here suggesting good tools

But if you are intending to remove png-drawables (or other **image files**), you should also consider moving all the drawable-xxxx folders out of your project into a temporary folder, then do a rebuild all, and take a look at the build message list which will tell you which ones are missing.

This can be specially useful if you want to get an overview of which resources you are effectively using and maybe replace them with an icon font or svg resources, possibly with the help of the [Android Iconics](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics) library.

Comment: this is time consuming, but I agree this is too, a solution. I am doing this right now

Answer (score 1):

`shift` double click on Windows then type "unused", you will find an option `Remove unused Resources`,
 also

```
 android {
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
            }
   }
}
```

when you set these settings on, AS will automatically remove unused resources.

Answer (score 0):

Android Assets Viewer is designed to help visually inspect the graphics packed (as drawables) within your .apk (you can also just upload a zip file of your res folder if you prefer):

http://www.cellebellum.net/AndroidAssetsViewer/

So for removing unused resources, this might work well in tandem with the Lint checks to help make sure everything that should be there is. It also helps you identify a few other potential problems with your drawables: wrong bucket, wrong graphic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After you run Lint in Android Studio and find all the unused resources, you can click on one of them from the Inspection tab. It provides some detail about the issue and a few options to fix it. One of them is Remove All Unused Resources. Selecting that option deletes all the unused resources.