# Android delete unused resources

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all unused resources from an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373482/remove-all-unused-resources-from-an-android-project)

I am working on one project which is an huge project. It consists of many images and layouts.
I need to delete the unused images and layouts from the project from just one Command. When i googled  http://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/ i saw this link for android.

but there is no much information available for the same.
Can anybody help me to know the steps to remove unused files.

Thanks

Comment: You can try this [programm](https://github.com/matzuk/RemovingAndroidUnusedResources) for android projects

Answer (score 1):

Update to ADT 16 and use [Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint). It is really amazing tool.

> Android Lint is a new tool for ADT 16 (and Tools 16) which scans Android project sources for potential bugs.

```
Here are some examples of the types of errors that it looks for:

- Missing translations (and unused translations)
- Layout performance problems (all the issues the old layoutopt tool used to find, and more)
- Unused resources
- Inconsistent array sizes (when arrays are defined in multiple configurations)
- Accessibility and internationalization problems (hardcoded strings, missing contentDescription, etc)
- Icon problems (like missing densities, duplicate icons, wrong sizes, etc)
- Usability problems (like not specifying an input type on a text field)
- Manifest errors
and many more.
```