# How to check reference from String.xml

Tags: android

Is there any way to check String reference from String.xml

I have many String in String.xml but i want to remove some unused String's.
 i am not finding any way to check that which String used by other class's.

so how can i get infomation about used String's  in String.xml

if i check one by one it will take whole day.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373482/remove-all-unused-resources-from-an-android-project

Comment: Delete any one of them and see whether it is referenced or not.if yes then keep it else remove it

Comment: Thanks for reply Akash.This Trick is not proper  .i am looking for any good method.if i ll not find it.then i ll use your trick at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lint can help you. Try to check your project. 
Look at the screen :
[image]

Comment: I would agree on using LINT...kudos

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse if you updated android sdk Lint tool will automatically come with a plugin, it will give warnings about xml resources which are not referenced.

Check this link

http://tools.android.com/recent/neweclipselintui

Answer (score 0):

On the command line, you can use [`android lint`](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/) (as said in [the comment by @Lalit Poptani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426074/how-to-check-reference-from-string-xml#comment15072599_11426074)). Inside the project, you just type

```
ant lint
```

The warnings look like

> Warning: The resource R.string.... appears to be unused
>   [UnusedResources]
>        [lint]     some text