# Android Studio: How can I see which resources are not used?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

Is there a way in Android Studio to see unused resources?

For example, I have a large list of drawables, say icons, and I want to know if there are any that are not used in my app so that I can delete them. Is there a way to see that?

I'm on Mac.

Comment: You can refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31669368/3343174) :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these two tools useful

- [Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint)
- [Gradle Resource shrink](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking)

Answer (score 2):

Try this in command line:

```
lint --check UnusedResources <project_directory>
```