# How to clean up unused resource files in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, resource-cleanup

I just completed my android app. I want to clean up the unused layout files and other resource files such as images and drawables and strings which are not referenced in the actual code. How do I do that? Is there any option to do this in Android Studio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all unused resources from an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373482/remove-all-unused-resources-from-an-android-project)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can able to remove unused resources by following way.

1. `Analyze` > `Inspect Code` and find **Unused Declarations and Methods**.
2. Android Studio -> **Menu** -> **Refactor** -> **Remove Unused Resources**.

Comment: Beware of running the automatic Removal these days. The detection phase is not 100% perfect, given current tooling.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily search for unused resources from Android Studio.
Select res folder ->  Just press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+i and type "unused resources" (without quotes). That will execute lint. Super easy way to run lint commands (and other stuff from IDE).

Click on remove all unused resources.