# How to reduce apk size if more than 60% of accumolate lib folder after apk anlysis?

Tags: android

I have seen bellow report from my .apk using android build->analysis apk. 
[image]

I have used progrud bellow like

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        //Other parameters
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
```

But My **debug apk** size is **26.9 MB**. When I want to build for **release apk** then its size become  **23.5 MB**. It is big in size. 
Please help me for reduce my apk or reduce at least 60%. Thanks Enamul

Comment: [Reduce the APK size | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size)

Comment: https://medium.com/exploring-code/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod I have followed but 26.9 MB become  23.5MB

Comment: shrinkResources true & minifyEnabled true works greatly

Comment: @Monish  I have used these..

Comment: @EnamulHaque then download the .so files at run time ... 26-16 = 10 mb

Answer (score 5):

**Splitting apk is a good solution. But here is once more trick.**

If you just include `armeabi-v7a` in your apk, that will be fine unless you support < 4.4 android versions.

`ARMv6` is no longer supported by Android since android 4.4 (Oct 13)

See this [Unity Statics](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808222202/http://hwstats.unity3d.com:80/mobile/cpu-android.html), You just need to include `ARMv7` & `Intelx86` to make support your app 100% devices.

Now what you have to do is just include `ARMv7` & `x86` in your app. See [abiFilter](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds).

- Add this to your app level `build.gradle`

  `buildTypes {
      release {
          ndk {
              abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
          }
      }`
- Press Sync
- Build and check size

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way it is to build apk for each `abi`

**Here is short example**:

```
android {
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "mips", "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
}
```

You will get apk's for different architectures with single JNI lib in it.

But you also need to implement special versioning process for it, so there will be no problem to upload apk in **Google Play**.

**Like this**:

```
android {
    def abiCodes = ['mips':1, 'x86':2, 'x86_64':3, 'armeabi':4, 'armeabi-v7a':5, 'arm64-v8a':6]
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each {
            output ->
                def abiName = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                output.versionCodeOverride = abiCodes.get(abiName, 0) * 100000 + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use lint and remove unwanted resources from your code.
This is link
[Remove all unused resources from an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373482/remove-all-unused-resources-from-an-android-project)

It may help you.