# Remove all unused resources from android project not working

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I'm trying to remove all unused resources from the project but seems like this feature doesn't work for that project. I've tried to remove unused resources from another project and it worked fine. I also added some dummy string to my project to check if it will work but it didn't. Any ideas why this feature doesn't work?

[image]

Comment: See also: [Remove all unused resources from an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373482/remove-all-unused-resources-from-an-android-project)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this:
Analyzed -> Run Inspection by Name. and then find unused resourced:

[image]

This will find your unused resources and then you can delete them