# How to remove unused resources from android studio 3.6.1 project?

Tags: android, android-resources

Recently I updated my android studio to 3.6.1 but after **`inspecting code`** from

> **`Analyze Menu -> Inspect Code`**

I am unable to find **`Android -> Performance`** to remove an unused resource.

So how to remove unused resources from the **`inspect code`** menu.? not from **`Refactor Menu`**.

Comment: You can remove from Refactor -> Remove Unused Resources

Comment: @MariaKayani Yes but Refactor menu remove as a whole not by choice.

Comment: With Android view mode on your project right-click into the module -> Refactor -> Remove Unused Resources...

Comment: See also: [Remove all unused resources from an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373482/remove-all-unused-resources-from-an-android-project)